# Theme options WP Editor

Tags: functions, theme-options, options, wp-editor

My text editor in Theme Options doesn't have font color option. How can I add that? I've searched around the web, but no luck. On regular pages and posts I can see the font color option.

I'm using Options framework. Here's the code snippet:

```
$options[] = array(
        'name' => __('Main text block', 'options_check'),
        'id' => 'main_text_editor',
        'type' => 'editor',
        'settings' => $wp_editor_settings );
```

Comment: Can you explain your question with the arguments, there you pass in the var `$wp_editor_settings`. It is much helpful to understand your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theme options, I had to define wp_editor_settings. So, just in options.php, I used:

```
//WP_editor settigs
    $wp_editor_settings = array(
        'wpautop' => true, // Default
        'textarea_rows' => 15,
        'tinymce' => array( 
            'plugins' => 'fullscreen,wordpress,wplink, textcolor'
        ));
```

Basically, I'm adding tinymce plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the font color inside the TinyMCE editor. The `wp_editor()` function have the settings parameter, there you reference to an var like ``.

This parameter need a array and this array can use a lot of parameters. The follow example demonstrate this and the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Arguments) have also a documentation.

```
$settings = array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' =>  false,
    'textarea_name' => 'test-editor',
    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10),
    'tabindex' => '',
    'editor_css' => '',
    'editor_class' => '',
    'teeny' => true,
    'dfw' => true,
    'tinymce' => array(
          'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline' 
    ),
    'quicktags' => false
);
wp_editor( 'Text in editor', 'test-editor', $settings );
```

The argument inside the array `tinymce` accept also a array with different parameters to customize the editor bar.

The follow buttons was in default defined for the 'teeny' buttons, the PressThis bar, different from the default editor:

```
'teeny_mce_buttons',
array( 
    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'blockquote', 'strikethrough', 'bullist',   
    'numlist', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'undo', 
    'redo', 'link', 'unlink', 'fullscreen'
)
```

Also is the second row possibel:

```
'mce_buttons_2'
array( 
    'formatselect', 'underline', 'alignjustify', 'forecolor', 'pastetext',
    'removeformat', 'charmap', 'outdent', 'indent', 'undo', 'redo'
)
```

### Default WP Editor Settings

```
    $set = wp_parse_args( $settings, array(
        'wpautop'             => true,
        'media_buttons'       => true,
        'default_editor'      => '',
        'drag_drop_upload'    => false,
        'textarea_name'       => $editor_id,
        'textarea_rows'       => 20,
        'tabindex'            => '',
        'tabfocus_elements'   => ':prev,:next',
        'editor_css'          => '',
        'editor_class'        => '',
        'teeny'               => false,
        'dfw'                 => false,
        '_content_editor_dfw' => false,
        'tinymce'             => true,
        'quicktags'           => true
    ) );
```

### Custom plugins in the TinyMCE editor

You can also add custom plugins for the TinyMCE in this settings array, like the follow example.

```
'tinymce' => array( 
    'plugins' => 'fullscreen, wordpress, wplink, textcolor'
)
```